# is there way to store all the objects of the class in the global array of objects in Parse in javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Below is the code

```
Parse.initialize("xx","xx");

var queryGroups = new Parse.Query("Group");
var arr = []; 
queryGroups.find({
       success: function(objects) {
        for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
            var g = new Object();
            g["whatsAppGroupName"] = objects[i].get("whatsAppGroupName");
            g["whatsAppGroupDescription"] = objects[i].get("whatsAppGroupDescription");
            g["entryCriteria"] = objects[i].get("entryCriteria");
            g["parent"] = objects[i].get("parent");
            arr.push(g);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            console.log("whatsAppGroupName = " + arr[i].whatsAppGroupName);
        }       
       },
       error: function(error) {
           console.log("An error occured :(");
       }
});
```

Now the problem is that for loop which prints to console works fine inside find function but outside the find function for loop doesn't work, seems that data is not stored in the global array. So, is there way to store the data in the global array so that data can be  used later. I have searched on the internet and google, but not able to find the better explanation.

Comment: How did you know that it does not work?

Comment: Actually this whole code was inside the script tag and not inside the function, so when i ran the for loop outside the find call it not worked.

Comment: Yup, but its asynchronous, I just want to make sure that you check in the proper way.

Answer (score 1):

I realised that a service like parse.com exists, only today after reading your question.

Well then, you probably did something like

```
...
var arr = [];
queryGroups.find(...);
...
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log("whatsAppGroupName = " + arr[i].whatsAppGroupName);
}
```

If what you did isn't similar to the above, then your question is not clear. But assuming, you did something like that, `arr` has not been populated when your `for loop` started executing.

Why could it not have been populated? - I suppose the execution of `queryGroup.find()` makes an XHR request, an operation that happens asynchronously. So it's possible the outer `for loop` executes before the request has completed.

Anything you wish to do on completion of querying, should be done inside the `success` method. Because that method runs exactly after the `queryGroups.find()` completes a request successfully.

To verify the likelihood that you're iterating the array before it has been filled by `find()`, do this:

```
...
var arr = [], ready = false;
queryGroups.find({
    success: function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
            ...
            arr.push(something);
            ...
        }
        ready = true;
    }
    ...
});
...
// check every 100 milisecond if data is ready (i.e. arr has been populated)
setInterval(function(ready){
    if(ready){
        // yes, we've got data - might be 0 data though!
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            console.log("whatsAppGroupName = " + arr[i].whatsAppGroupName);
        }
    }
}, 100, ready);
```

Comment: Yeah thanks it works inside but the whole code when run with for loop outside i guess the for loop is executed before the success function...

Comment: @jain, you're welcome. Consider marking this as the answer if it helped you reach the correct resolution. When other people experience similar problem like you did it will help them immediately see that this answer is the correct one and can help the unto the right part.

Answer (score -1):

Try defining the variable g as global:-

```
var g;
Parse.initialize("HIL42pG8FRAx9AXasyyJAg5nXI6x2IifWh30AX5I","KUKOb5pz4GEbcbGAa8GVQrBQL7ER7DsV6m0PZLOL");

var queryGroups = new Parse.Query("Group");
var arr = []; 
queryGroups.find({
   success: function(objects) {
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        g = new Object();
        g["whatsAppGroupName"] = objects[i].get("whatsAppGroupName");
        g["whatsAppGroupDescription"] = objects[i].get("whatsAppGroupDescription");
        g["entryCriteria"] = objects[i].get("entryCriteria");
        g["parent"] = objects[i].get("parent");
        arr.push(g);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        console.log("whatsAppGroupName = " + arr[i].whatsAppGroupName);
    }       
   },
   error: function(error) {
       console.log("An error occured :(");
   }
});
```

Check the value of g after completing the find call.

Comment: did you consider that the internal operations of `find()` may yet not have completed after 3 seconds, or that the request may not be successful?

Comment: @SultanBaby I have given 3 second estimated time. As this is an async call it is not sure you will get after 3 second....

Comment: we should always make defensive designs, in that regard making estimates does not guarantee code reliability.